# It is possible to share something directly in a specific social network in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, share

I have an Ionic app and I want to be able to share directly to a determined social network instead of opening the share list and let the user decide where it wants to share. I mean, the user clicks the Facebook share button and facebook opens directly in the post edit mode.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to force the user to any network. It's just that my app deals with posting in many social networks and I want the user to make the less possible effort to post. So that would remove one scroll and one click out of the way per network.

But the only share plugin Iconic has is @capacitor/share and AFAIU it doesn't have this capability.

Is this even possible ? If it isn't, does React Native has this capability ? I would change FWs if it has and Ionic doesn't.